# Put some delay between two batch jobs

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduler, spring-scheduled

I have created two batch jobs and both jobs have initial delay of 20 seconds. Now I want to put some delay between those 2 jobs. If **Job1** is running then **Job2** has to wait for some seconds and then execute only if **Job1** is done similarly if **Job2** is running then **Job1** has to wait for some seconds and then execute only if **Job2** is done.

```
@Component
public class Job1{

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000)
    public void execute() {
        //business logic
    }
}

@Component
public class Job2{

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000)
    public void execute() {
        //business logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Only one task can be running at one moment?

Comment: yes. only one task should run at one moment. if Job1 is running then Job2 should wait for Job1 to be finished and vice versa.

Comment: Do the jobs have to be initialized by separate @Scheduled-annotated methods? An option would be to have a single @Scheduled method which runs both these `execute()`methods, and you could control the concurrency directly.

Comment: Yes. it has to be separate.

Comment: To be honest, your solution looks like overkill. Maybe ScheduledExecutorService with single thread could help you.

Comment: You could achieve something like your required behaviour by introducing a runner-component with a method `synchronized void run(Runnable runnable)` which you call from your execute-classes with the business logic as the runnable argument.

Comment: @user16320675 if you see my code, both jobs will start every 20 seconds and it will execute the logic parallelly. but here I want to put some delay between the execution so that they will not execute parallelly.

Comment: The "standard" way for managing concurrency in a scnario like this would be a semaphore: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html . Your jobs acquire the same semaphore (with a single available resource) when they start and releases it when they finishe. If one job is executing while the other starts, it blocks until the other finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the behaviour by having the jobs run in a single synchronized method, for example by introducing a class which has a method to execute a synchronized method, i.e.

```
@Component
class SingleThreadJobRunner {
    synchronized void run(Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

A full working example which utilizes this class across different @Scheduled-methods:

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);
    }
}

@Component
class SingleThreadJobRunner {
    synchronized void run(Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run();
    }
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Job1 {
    private final SingleThreadJobRunner singleThreadJobRunner;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void execute() {
        singleThreadJobRunner.run(() -> {
            System.out.print("job 1 started - ");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.println("job 1 completed");

        });
    }
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Job2 {
    private final SingleThreadJobRunner singleThreadJobRunner;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1500)
    public void execute() {
        singleThreadJobRunner.run(() -> {
            System.out.print("job 2 started - ");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.println("job 2 completed");
        });
    }
}
```

Varying rates and sleep-times were used to show that the jobs never overlap. If you need the delay between the methods which you mention in your question, this could be added to the `run()`-method.

Comment: I found a way to handle this situation. your solution helped me to get the proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue. called the business logic inside a synchronized block so both the job can't run in parallel.

If Job1 is running then Job2 will wait for some seconds and then execute only if Job1 is done similarly if Job2 is running then Job1 will wait for some seconds and then execute only if Job2 is done.

```
@Component
public class Job1{

    @Autowired
    private ISyncExecuteService syncExecuteService;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000)
    public void execute() {
       syncExecuteService.execute("job1");
    }
}

@Component
public class Job2{

    @Autowired
    private ISyncExecuteService syncExecuteService;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000)
    public void execute() {
        syncExecuteService.execute("job2");
    }
}

@Component
public class SyncExecuteServiceImpl implements ISyncExecuteService{
    @Override
    public void execute(String jobType) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (jobType.equals("job1")) {
                executeJob1();
            } else if (jobType.equals("job2")){
                executeJob2();
            }
        }
    }

    private void executeJob1(){
        //business logic for batch job 1;
    }

    private void executeJob2(){
        //business logic for batch job 2;
    }
}
```